# Ddos атака прокси

Tags: iptables, ddos, proxy

Вообщем, имеется софтина + список прокси. Софтина шлет запросы через тысячи прокси на сервер(программа), сама программа-сервер ложится, отследить это оочень сложно. Запросы не флудятся, то есть отличить от человека я не знаю как. Как можно определить прокси ли конектится или реальный юзер. Сейчас в фаерволе блокирую просто некоторые прокси сам, закрыл доступ левым странам, блокирую по портам прокси, все бы ничего но теперь пошли приватные прокси, порты абсолютно разные, вычислить еще сложнее...ОС Debian7 x64 minimal, канал в 200мб, да и сама тачка жирная.

Comment: смотрите заголовки, и ещё момент, как вы определяете что это ддос а не просто какой-нить слэшдот эффект ?

Comment: Знаю, типовая атака.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из вариантов - отслеживать в заголовках

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER']
```